# Factory girl generate two variables but RecordNotUnique

Tags: ruby, factory-bot

I have a `User` model class, i want to generate two instance variables to make some tests.

```
let (:user) {FactoryGirl.create :user,:with_events}
let (:user1) {FactoryGirl.create :user,:with_events}
```

But i got the error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique:
       Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry 'AlBw1S27GE6wQIgzHM2TmZxSaHXLbhuQIg08NyI98Cg' for key 'index_users_on_access_token': INSERT INTO `users` 



I checked AlBw1S27GE6wQIgzHM2TmZxSaHXLbhuQIg08NyI98Cg is user1's access_token already. But why did user1 use the same **access_token**?
```

And it seems **SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(32)** was called only once? Why access_token isn't unique?

PS:

factories.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do |f|

  factory :user do
    password      "123123"
    sequence(:name){|n| "张三#{n}" }
    access_token  SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(32)
    expired       Time.now + FSpace::USER_TOKEN_EXPIRED_TIMES
  end

  factory :event do 
    end_date      "2015-05-30"
    is_countdown  "1"
    start_date    "2015-03-17"
    sequence(:name){|n| "我的生日#{n}" }
  end


  trait :with_events do
    after :create do |user|
      FactoryGirl.create_list :event, 3, :user => user
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the syntax you've used,

```
access_token SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(32)
```

The value is evaluated only once, when the factory is defined.

If you want the value to be evaluated each time the factory is used then you need to use the block based syntax.

```
access_token { SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(32) }
```

In the documentation they call this [lazy attributes](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#Lazy_Attributes)

Comment: Hi Frederick Cheung, after i created user and user1 both with 3 events, why i test get wrong, thanks!  ```Failure/Error: expect(json["events"].count).to eq 6```